# Adapting 1/2 hose to sink

Tags: plumbing, faucet, sink, adapter

Im building a simple low pressure foot pump operated sink. What adaptor should I be looking for to go from typical (USA) male faucet threads to 1/2 hose barb?

I'm new to plumbing and have found surprisingly little info on this online.

Comment: It depends on the style of faucet if I understand the question but 1/2” plumbing threads are based on national pipe thread the inside diameter is used and the thread is tapered . I want to say 12 threads per inch for 1/2”. If you are asking about the threads on a kitchen faucet out put there are several sizes but the standard thread on things like a hose bib out side is 3/4” same thread ouch and taper as 1/2” npt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What adaptor should I be looking for to go from typical (USA) male faucet threads to 1/2 hose barb?

First you will need to ascertain what threads your faucet spout has (there are many); a faucet thread gauge will help (these can be found in plumbing shops and *sometimes* in the plumbing dept. of "big box" stores):
[image]

**Then** you will need to adapt to a thread for which barbed fittings are commonly available. In my area it is easiest to adapt your faucet to *pipe thread*, because many *pipe thread* to *barb* adapters are available:

example of faucet thread to pipe thread adapter:
[image]

**Then** you need a *pipe thread* to *barb* adapter:

example of *pipe thread* to *barb* adapter:

[image]

I have never seen a single adapter that will work for this, so you need two. Also, whether or not you convert your faucet to pipe or to garden hose thread, then to barb, will depend on availability of fittings in your area.

Answer (score 0):

Just Googling around a bit, it looks like there's some options.

**Disclaimer:** These are just search results, not brand or store recommendations. I used the search terms: `faucet to 1/2" hose barb adapter`.

---

> Brass Quick Garden Water Tap Connector 1/2 Inch to 3/4 Inch Universal Pipe Fitting Adapter Easy Connect Home Yard/Washing Machine Thread Water Faucet

[https://www.amazon.com/Connector-Universal-Fitting-Adapter-Connect/dp/B078JP7HWS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078JP7HWS)

---

> 1/2 in. Drip-Lock Hose Faucet Adapter

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Orbit-1-2-in-Drip-Lock-Hose-Faucet-Adapter-67495/301043975

---

This one looks to need a standard faucet to garden hose adapter to meet what you're looking for.

> 1/2" ID Hose x Swivel FGHT Nylon Swivel Female Insert

https://www.usplastic.com/catalog/item.aspx?sku=63003&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6v7UnPr24wIVhsBkCh2h8wqIEAQYCyABEgIJmvD_BwE

---

This one also looks to need a standard faucet to garden hose adapter, but at least it's brass.

> Brass Fitting - 3/4" Male Garden Hose X 1/2" OD Barb | Compact

https://www.ontariobeerkegs.com/Brass_Fitting_3_4_MGH_x_1_2_Barb_Compact_p/brass-3-4-mgh-x-1-2-barb-comp.htm

---

I can find plenty of faucet to 1/4" adapters, but not a many to 1/2". There's also plenty of adapters to a standard garden hose, but that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for either.

Normally shopping suggestions aren't a good fit for this site, but I think trying to find a non-standard part might be. If people disagree, please vote on the Question, not my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is just a garden hose repair end.  Available at most hardware stores.  These usually come with a brass barbed connector and a hose clamp.  A second type has a plastic barbed end and two plastic halves that are bolted together around the outside of the hose.  Usually available in 1/2" and 5/8"

1/2" black poly line is usually closer to 5/8" ID.